# Inno Setup won't install to "Program Files" on Win 7 for limited user

Tags: permissions, inno-setup, limited-user

Per the subject... I made a Setup.exe with Inno Setup which is supposed to
install to "{pf}{#MyAppName}". It does so on Win XP and also Win 7 if I'm
logged in with admin rights, but if I try on Win 7 as a limited user, I get
this error message:

"Setup was unable to create the directory C:\Program Files\AppName".

What to do? I don't want (or need) the user to install as an admin.

Comment: Please state if you [ask the question elsewhere](http://news.jrsoftware.org/read/article.php?id=93882&group=jrsoftware.innosetup#93882) to avoid duplicate effort answering.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to install to `%ProgramFiles%`, you do need to install as an admin. Regular users don't have write access to `%ProgramFiles%` directory.

If installing to `%ProgramFiles%` is not a requirement, just let the user pick a destination directory, or install to `{localappdata}` instead of `{pf}`. `{localappdata}` is guaranteed to be writable for it's owner. It expands to something like `C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Local`.

You can also install to `{pf}` if running as admin and to `{localappdata}` if running as restricted user; use [IsAdminLoggedOn](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_privilegesrequired) to decide.

If installing to `%ProgramFiles%` is a must, you have no choice but to run as admin.
For this to work correctly, make sure that your .iss file either does not define [PrivilegesRequired](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_privilegesrequired) option, or it's set to `admin`. Then, when an unprivileged user runs the installer, a UAC prompt will appear asking for credentials with enough access rights (unless UAC is disabled, in which case the only way to install is Run As).

Comment: Thanks, there is no need for admin rights for my app, so I'll just default it to C:\AppName instead.

Comment: @User2571 - note that by default C:\ is unwritable by non-admin users too.